# Split using multiple keywords using regex

Tags: ruby, split

Well I have a string containing (actually without line breaks)

```html
<td class="coll-1 name">
  <a href="/sub/48/0/" class="icon"><i class="flaticon-divx"></i></a>
  <a href="/torrent/2349324/some-stuuf-here/">SAME stuff here</a>
  <span class="comments"><i class="flaticon-message"></i>1</span>
</td>
```

and I want an array to store the string which is split using `href="` and `/">` specifically. How can i do that. I have tried this out.

```
new_array=my_string.split(/ href="  ,   \/">/)
```

**Edit:**

```
.split(/href="/)
```

This works  out too good but not with the other part.

```
.split(/\/">/)
```

Similarly this works too But i am unable to combine them together into 1 line.

Comment: [You can't parse (X)HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/477037). Anyway – what is your expected result?

Comment: @Stefan `/torrent/2349324/some-stuuf-here` is my expected result.

Comment: Why not `/sub/48/0/`? How do you determine the correct link?

Comment: @Stefan Thats the whole point. What I am trying is to make a bot that gives me the `/torrent/2349324/some-stuuf-here/` from a webpage. I have the very line from the webpage which is stored in `my_string`. I just want to extract the address from it.
I determine the correct link by knowing that the correct link ends right with `/">` every time.

Comment: Please edit your question rather than elaborating in comments. Not all readers see all comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of *lookahead* and *lookbehind*, like this:

```
my_string.scan(/(?<=href=").*(?=\/">)/)
#=> ["/torrent/2349324/some-stuuf-here"]
```

This will return an array with all occurrences of `href=" ... /">` with only the `...` part (which can be any string).

Or you can get everything that matches `href=".../">` and then remove `href="` and the trailing `/">`, something like this:

```
my_string.scan(/(?:href=".*\/">)/).map { |e| e.gsub(/(href="|\/">)/, "") }
#=> ["/torrent/2349324/some-stuuf-here"]
```

This will return an array of all instances that match `/href=".*\/">/`.

> How do i split using 2 keywords using regex

You can use a `|` to denote an *or* in regex, like this:

```
my_string.split(/(?:href="|/">)/)
```

Comment: Thank You very much Sir this works very well and also does what is needed. But with respect it does not answer my question. The question is "How do i split using 2 keywords using regex" in my case. Basically How do i merge those 2 regex splits. 
The point here is to learn and not just to come to the answer. The required string could be extracted by splitting the string with `"` and then selecting the 9th index but sincerely I want to learn and not just jump to the conclusions. Thanks anyways.
Please add the solution to your answer. Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: @Rishav You can use `|` to denote _or_, for example: `my_string.split(/(?:href="|/">)/)` will split either with `href="` or with `/">`. Is that what your are looking for?

Comment: Damn That effort though. Upvoting. :)

Answer (score 2):

Given this string:

```
string = <<-HTML
  <td class="coll-1 name">
    <a href="/sub/48/0/" class="icon"><i class="flaticon-divx"></i></a>
    <a href="/torrent/2349324/some-stuuf-here/">SAME stuff here</a>
    <span class="comments"><i class="flaticon-message"></i>1</span>
  </td>
HTML
```

and assuming that the correct link is the one without `icon` class, you could use the CSS selector `a:not(.icon)`, for example via [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org):

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(string)

doc.at_css('a:not(.icon)')[:href]
#=> "/torrent/2349324/some-stuuf-here/"
```

Comment: Above my head. xD

Comment: @Rishav what exactly? CSS selectors?

Comment: Your solution is giving the required result after installing the gem though.  But really I know only basic Ruby and batch commands. 
Icon class 
CSS n all r too far. 
Thanks though.
Learned something.